# AZURE T-SQL calculations output to new VIEW

Tags: sql, t-sql, azure-sql-database

I have the following problem that I would like to solve.

A table has a column `TIMEIN` and I want to add a column `TIMEOUT`, this should take the value of `TIMEIN` plus 60sec unless the next `TIMEIN` is closer.

So:

```
ID PROJECTCODE  TIMEIN  TIMEOUT
----------------------------------
1  25847        35      79   = less as 60 seconds in between 35(id1) and 80(id2)
2  25847        80      140  = more as 60 seconds in between 80(id2) and 158(id3)
3  25847        158     218  = 60 added because there is no bigger time as 158sec.
4  25847        35      79   = less as 60 seconds in between 35(id1) and 80(id2)
```

Important to know is that the id's don't follow up, and there could be as well two times or more the same time. How would I do that? Any good ideas or documentation I could follow?

Comment: What DBMS are you using?  (ex. SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle)

Comment: [so] is *not* a free code writing service. You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing more research](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[mcve]**. I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour].

Comment: Yes i know that and i have done so many times, i am therefor not asking YOU to write it but i am asking as you read "Any good idea's or documentation i could follow?" SO i got a starting point.

Comment: would be helpful if you provided your DBMS but most of them have lead / lag analytic function that would work here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `LEAD()` to access the next row's value, then a `CASE` statement to determine whether to use 60 seconds or not.  Something like this:

```
SELECT ID, 
       PROJECTCODE, 
       TIMEIN,
       CASE WHEN LEAD(TIMEIN) OVER (ORDER BY ID) - TIMEIN < 60
            THEN LEAD(TIMEIN) OVER (ORDER BY ID) - 1
            ELSE TIMEIN + 60
       END AS TIMEOUT
FROM TimesTable
```

Might need to add a `PARTITION BY PROJECTCODE`, but it's unclear from the sample data.

Comment: Thank you Aaron you helped me along a great deal already, more as i asked for.

Comment: sorry was logged off for little time